# How do I add order now button and proceed them to a paypal order page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, paypal

I have a price calculator, not the most beautiful price calculator form. So there are 4 tabs in the calculator, each for having a different number of days. I want to add a order now button to each of the tab below. and since the end user will choose how many pages he want, how can I make the code know that the person has selected 'n' number of pages and that much payment has to be made when he goes to paypal order page. Like paypal will know that the person has selected 4 pages and paypal will charge for 4 pages.

```
<style>
.currencyinput {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.currencyinput input {
    border: 0;
}


@charset "UTF-8";


body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.42em;
  color:#A7A1AE;
  background-color:#1F2739;
}

h1 {
  font-size:3em; 
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4DC3FA;
}

h2 {
  font-size:1em; 
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height:1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  color: #FB667A;
}

h2 a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FB667A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blue { color: #185875; }
.yellow { color: #FFF842; }

.container th h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 1em;
    width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td, .container th {
       padding-bottom: 1%;
      padding-top: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left:2%;  
}

/* Background-color of the odd rows */
.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #323C50;
}

/* Background-color of the even rows */
.container tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
      background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container td:first-child { color: #FB667A; }

.container tr:hover {
   background-color: #464A52;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
            box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;

  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);

  transition-delay: 0s;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.container td:nth-child(4),
.container th:nth-child(4) { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

**HTML code**

```
<table class="container">
<tr><h1>
Online Shop
</h1></tr>
<td>
<div id="purhcaseForm">
    <form id="purchase1">

      <br> Please Select Number of Pages:
      <br>
      <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",8);' value='-' />
      <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",8);' value='+' />
      <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0" />
     <span class="currencyinput">$<input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" /></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div id="purhcaseForm">
    <form id="purchase2">

      <br> Please Select Number of Pages:
      <br>
      <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty1",-1,"total1",7);' value='-' />
      <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty1",1,"total1",7);' value='+' />
      <input type='text' name='qty1' id='qty1' readonly=true value="0" />
      <span class="currencyinput">$ <input type='text' name='total1' id='total1' value="0" /></span>
    </form>
  </div>
  </td>
<td>
  <div id="purhcaseForm">
    <form id="purchase3">

      <br> Please Select Number of Pages:
      <br>
      <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty2",-1,"total2",6);' value='-' />
      <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty2",1,"total2",6);' value='+' />
      <input type='text' name='qty2' id='qty2' readonly=true value="0" />
      <span class="currencyinput">$  <input type='text' name='total2' id='total2' value="0" /></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div id="purhcaseForm">
    <form id="purchase4">

      <br> Please Select Number of Pages:
      <br>
      <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty3",-1,"total3",5);' value='-' />
      <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty3",1,"total3",5);' value='+' />
      <input type='text' name='qty3' id='qty3' readonly=true value="0" />
      <span class="currencyinput">$ <input type='text' name='total3' id='total3' value="0" /></span>
    </form>
  </div>
  </td>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can  you not create paypal pay buttons within paypal?  It looks like you would want to create 4 different buttons and just add that to the bottom of each section and let PayPal do the work for you.

Comment: yeah I want to create 4 different buttons and just add that to the bottom of each section and let PayPal do the work for me. Is there a way to that?

Comment: Yeah I want to create a paypal pay button but how will paypal know that the user has selected 8 pages and the amount let's say is $50. So paypal gonna know that automatically based on my code?

Comment: I would make multiple buttons.  1 button = X Pages for $X price.  Predefined..  This way clicking that button is for THAT package.  And just repeat the process for every option.

Comment: can you show me the code of that in jsfiddle? just for one tab. i will do the rest. i just need to have the idea of how to implement it, i searched for it everywhere but couldn't find the exact answer

Comment: I can't really show you.  You have to log into your Paypal account and generate the buttons which will give you an Embed code.  https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside